# talend component tRssInput with authentification to query an atomfeed

Tags: authentication, talend, atom-feed

I have to retrieve feed from an atomfeed in oracle fusion using Talend.

I added a tRssInput component to my job. I can paste the URL of my feed. But since the feed is private to my organisation, I need to pass my authentication.

But the component don't have any param to enter the authentication.

Am I using the right component ?

Comment: well it depends of your authentication method, but the component doesn't seem to take token or other methods. So maybe try looking to the web components of talend like tHttpRequest, tRest, tRestClient, ... they might be more helpful in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted talend directly and the tRssInput only support the public feed.

I will use the tRssClient component and fetch all the rows and filter them. Not optimal. But it's working.